# web.config - deny all users to specific folder and subdirectories except for authenicated roles

Tags: iis-7, web-config, directory

I am having an issue trying to prevent all users/connections from accessing a download folder "files" and all subs and files therein. I only want to allow authenticated users in specific Roles to have access to the files. The files folder is under root.
./web.config
./files/subfolder1/files in here

my web.config I have this

```
<location path="files" allowOverride="false">
<system.web>
  <authorization>

    <allow roles="Admin, Fieldworker, Supervisor, Accounting" />
     <deny users="*" />

  </authorization>  
</system.web>
```

**The problem is not only are all users blocked, but also my authenticated users in the Admin and other roles are blocked.** 
If I add  above  then my "admin" user can access the files, but then so can any unauthenticated user... which I do not get why   would allow other users access?

My web server is IIS7.
Other related entries in web.config

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
  <remove name="ScriptModule" />
  <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler"   type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0,   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />  

    <add  name="FormsAuthenticationModule"    type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    <remove  name="UrlAuthorization" />
    <add  name="UrlAuthorization"   type="System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule"  />
    <remove  name="DefaultAuthentication" />  
    <add  name="DefaultAuthentication"  type="System.Web.Security.DefaultAuthenticationModule" />


</modules>
```

Thanks in advance for help on this!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a duplicate of: [how to protect uploaded documents from direct access in web forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30111761/how-to-protect-uploaded-documents-from-direct-access-in-web-forms/30113959#30113959)

You need to use a `<location>` element:

```
   <location path="Logon.aspx">
    <system.web>
     <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
     </authorization>
    </system.web>
   </location>
```

Comment: Since my posting, I discovered main issue is site is on IIS 6 and I need to move it to IIS7 or up to get forms authentication to protected all type of files. I not sure yet if moving site will help solve the issue I posted yet or not. Thank you.