# how to protect uploaded documents from direct access in web forms

Tags: asp.net, security, iis-7

I have a c#.net application that allows users to upload documents.  The documents are then scanned for malware and saved.  These documents are saved in a share file and in an uploads folder.  The share file is on the intranet on a separate server.  The uploads folder sits in the same directory as the application, but is not part of the application.  The host server is running iis 7 with directory listing off.

The issue is that if an outside user is able to guess the naming convention and the file name, they can type that into a browser and view the document.

The application runs under a user account.  We have tried setting the permissions on the uploads folder to only allow the applications user account access, which did not work.

I also tried adding a web config to the folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="application_user_account" />
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This did not work when placed inside the uploads folder, but when it was accidentally placed in a folder one level up, the server denied all users access to all the applications hosted in the environment.

Does anyone have a solution for preventing direct access to the uploads folder in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to checkout the `<location>` node: [Click Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
   <location path="Logon.aspx">
     <system.web>
       <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
       </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

This seems to be a duplicate of: [How to restrict folder access in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776847/how-to-restrict-folder-access-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 1):

Move the uploads folder into `App_Data`.

e.g. `~/App_Data/Uploads`

`App_Data` is a special folder that cannot be read from the web.

Any attempt at navigating to `example.com/App_Data/Uploads/Foo.docx` will result in an authorisation error. e.g. An [`HTTP 403 Forbidden`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) HTTP response..

Comment: I have been trying to implement this solution today.  I found this article about using the App_Data folder:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31557/A-Beginner-s-Guide-to-ASP-NET-Application-Folders#h  Do I need to set up a database file that goes into the App_Data folder, which I can then insert files into?  Initially I was getting access denied errors, but after adjusting the path I was able to go through the application without throwing errors, however the files are not landing in my App_Data folder, and there is not an App_Data folder being created on the server containing these files.